# Unmount root from /boot partition? trying to fstransform /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root

Tags: filesystems, root-filesystem, migration

I am trying to transform `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` from xfs to ext4 using fstransform on my CentOS 7 VM. This is needed for a migration from another Centos 7 VM. The issue I am facing is the root filesystem type does not match between the VMs. `mount` shows `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` as the mounted root directory:
`/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)`

The transformation fails with `fsmove: ERROR: failed to remove source directory '//boot': Device or resource busy`.

Some other maybe helpful info:

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 30 14:19 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root -> ../dm-0
ls -l /dev/dm-0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 0 Aug 30 14:19 /dev/dm-0
```

Comment: Boot from live CD and do the operation.

Comment: please use proper syntax to format code and output